# Does P&CG need a new moderator?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, beta-status, moderators

P&CG is over 3 years old now. I hope one day it gets out of beta, I have a lot of fun here... even though I mostly pose questions rather than answering them myself.

Anyway, I checked the recent posting activity of our moderators, and... it was not great, both in the main site and in meta. @Doorknob [wrote it up quite well here 4 months ago](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/757/moderation-a-call-to-action).

I'd like to see more effort taken to moderate the site, especially from the users who are **currently** active, in addition to being well respected. I notice that none of the moderators weighed in, either as a comment or as an answer, to [Grace Note's post back in March](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/what-does-code-golfs-progress-look-like-right-now)

I am not taking anything away from the hard work the current moderators have done, and are currently putting in. In the past they have done a stellar job. But as [was recently said on MSO, **People change. Lives change.**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253376/1768232)

It's entirely possible that I'm completely wrong, and that all three moderators are working very hard handling flags and doing other work that I cannot see as a mere mortal. If this is the case, please let me and the rest of the community know, as it will make me feel much better.

I think we should contact the SE staff and ask them to make some changes. I don't know exactly what, I haven't been here long enough to make the best recommendation. But I would like to officially nominate @Doorknob to be a moderator, were he willing to take the reins.

Comment: I have openly supported (and still do) Doorknob to be a new mod, and I know others who have expressed the same view. Additionally, I have made my endorsement known to the SE community team.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Thanks! It's slightly overwhelming to see the amount of support people are giving me :P Users in chat have started mentioning others who they think would be good moderators. It would be nice if we could get "official" status on whether we will have a new mod (even though this was just posted a few hours ago; perhaps just a "we'll consider it"), and it would be great if the current mods could join us in chat to talk about this. (Perhaps having a Community Manager join us would be nice as well.)

Comment: The Community Team actually polled us recently on this and related issues (like were any of us itching to ditch the job). The consensus seemed to be that we are willing to stay on for the time being but would not mind the appointment of an additional mod. Further, I do not plan to run for the permanent post when the site graduates (and I have swung back to thinking that it will, albeit with [popularity-contest]s), so getting a new person on now would, perhaps, ease the transition. Uhm ... and yes, @Doorknob is an obvious choice.

Comment: I just got an email from SE asking whether I'd like to become a mod, so I guess this is official now. It'd be nice to get a meta post about the fact that a new mod will happen soon, but I can't make one right now. Oh, and thanks @dmckee.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd actually been poked about this a few times before now, which is why, as dmckee noted, I had been polling the moderators about their thoughts on the matter. I'm pleased to announce that starting today (some hours before now, as it were), Doorknob has joined the ranks of the pro tem moderators. All of the existing pro tem moderators will be retaining their positions. Enjoy!

Comment: Yeaaaaaaaaaaaah!

Answer (score 14):

I have a few things that I might be able to weigh in on:

- The community has gotten *drastically* better at self-moderation over the past few months or so. I'm not the only one who deletevotes anymore, and we're getting bad things closed much more quickly recently.
- As @Chris mentioned in that post I made a while ago, lots of modstuffs are hidden and not publicly visible. Moderators also are supposed to let the community lead, and our current mods are *fantastic* at doing this. I'm sure they'd all just love to nuke code-trolling or supress popularity-contest. (I wouldn't mind the mods hopping in for a 4th or 5th closevote or 3rd deletevote every once in a while though.)
- You could always ping the SE staff in [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta); they're quite good at responding there.
- I believe one or two of our current mods have mentioned handing back their diamonds. I'm sure they're excellent moderators, and they're all nice people. It'd be a shame to lose them, but if they think that others would be more suitable for the job, getting some new users in the mod team would be great.
- I've still been considering whether I'd want to get a diamond here, given the chance. I'll tentatively accept your nomination, but only if you don't make me kick out a current mod that still wants to be here, because that would feel terrible. :P